# Regular Expression to match a sentence which induces a word with specific suffix and defined end word

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching, regex-group

I'm trying to match a sentence which includes a word with a certain suffix and a specific word at the end.
For example sentence template would be;
"word word word (doesn't matter how many words before) word**SUFFIX**  thatspecificword."

I have tried this but could not match the words in the beginning.

```
(\w+)(SUFFIX)\s+thatspEcificword(suffix)?
```

Comment: Your example works fine (if you fix the uppercase "E" in `spEcific`): [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BVkaTc/1). Please provide a concrete example where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

#### Regex

```
.*(\b.*SUFFIX\b).*(specificword)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2DBwY/1)

#### Explanation

- `.*` - search for zero or more characters of any type
- `(\b.*SUFFIX\b)` - search for a word ending with SUFFIX
- `(specificword)$` - search for a "specificword" at the end of sentence.

#### Note:

If you cannot have matches where the entire word is SUFFIX, then you will need to change the regex to:

```
.*(\b.+SUFFIX\b).*(specificword)$
```

The `.+` ensures that there is at least one character before the SUFFIX

Answer (score 0):

As question tags are related to python, will try to answer from pythonic view.

If you simply want string ending with `SUFFIX thatspecificword`, then you may simply code like below -

```
pattern = "SUFFIX thatspecificword"
s = "word word word (doesn't matter how many words before) wordSUFFIX thatspecificword"
if s.endswith(pattern):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("match not found")
```

But if you want the string ending with `wordSUFFIX thatspecificword` where `word` can be any word i.e `SUFFIX` must be a word suffix then you might have a look into python built-in package named `re` which deals with regular expression -

```
import re

pattern = "\wSUFFIX thatspecificword$"
s = "word word word (doesn't matter how many words before) wordSUFFIX thatspecificword"
if re.search(pattern, s):
    print("match found")
else:
    print("match not found")
```